# Incorrect automatic Perl regex syntax

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

[Becoming a Perl bandit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180587/becomming-a-perl-bandit), in this question I had to [escape my regex expression](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/180587/3) `\:` to avoid funny syntaxing. Now on my [newest Perl question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180745/perl-letter-frequency-analysis-breaking-vignere), I encounter the same issue. Can this be fixed somehow?

- Should I just escape them all?
- Go to [google/code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) with the issue (doubtful if they do something about it)?
- Any other ideas? Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: I hate to be so cynical, but based on [this question (and the absence of an answer) on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289694/a-stack-exchange-fork-of-google-prettify), I have a feeling that syntax highlighting is pretty low on the priority list...

Comment: @Phrancis Thank you for the link, guess I should learn to live with it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is commonly accepted wisdom that ["Only `perl` can parse Perl"](https://everything2.com/title/Only+perl+can+parse+Perl).  *Every* syntax highlighter I have seen has bugs when highlighting Perl code, especially regexes.

I don't recommend modifying your code just to appease the syntax highlighter on Code Review.  You can either mention at the end of the question that the syntax highlighter is sloppy, or just turn off syntax highlighting by putting `<!-- language: lang-none -->` before your Perl code block.